# Evaluate $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$ By using residues. (To get the method verified)

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to know whether the following method is correct? More specifically whether the following curve is okay because that is not what we have done during the class.

Let $f(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^2}.$
And consider the two curves:
 $C_R=$ half circle with radius $R$ and center $0$ in the upper half plane.
 $L=$ straight line in the real axis $[-R,R].$
And $\zeta =C_R+L$.

Now to prove that $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{C_R}f(z)=0$:
Notice that for $z\in C_R$, where $z=x+iy$
$$\begin{align*}
|f(z)| & =\left| \frac{e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^2} \right|\\[8pt]
       & =\frac{|e^{iz}|}{|1+z^2|^2}\\[8pt]
       &= \frac{|e^{-y}e^{ix}|}{|1+z^2|^2}\\[8pt]
      &\leq \frac{e^{-y}}{|z|^2-1}\\[8pt]
      &=\frac{e^{-y}}{R^2-1}
\end{align*}$$
Notice that when $r\to\infty$, then $y\to\infty$
Hence by the [ML estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) we have
$$\left| \,\,\int\limits_{C_R}f(z)\,dz\, \right|\leq \frac{e^{-y}}{R^2-1} \cdot \pi R\to 0 \text{ when } R\to \infty.$$
And the remaining follows just by writing down $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$.

So I would like to know whether my choice of the contour $C_R$ is correct.

Appreciate your help....

Comment: I think you're correct: the semi-circular contour tends to 0 by ML estimate (or by Jordan's lemma) and the contour on the real line tends to your desired integral. So all that is to do is to compute the residue at $z=i$.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering whether having both $y$ and $R$ would make any trouble...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma

Comment: okay. Thank you..

Comment: You have a bound on the absolute value of the integral which depends on $y$; I'm not sure that makes sense. Anyway, you can forget about $y$, and use the easy bound $$|f(z)|\le\frac1{(R^2-1)^2}.$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you please explain how you obtained $1$ in the numerator.